# How to print Array with quotation marks in epp?

Tags: puppet, erb, epp

Given the hiera list (example values):

```
simplekey:
  hosts:
    - 'host1:8080'
    - 'host2:8080'
  [...]
```

When using ERB template, this code:

```
<% @simplekey.sort.each do |key, value| -%>
  <%= key %>: <%= value %>,
<% end -%>
```

results in

```
  hosts: ["host1:8080", "host2:8080"],
```

When migrating the code to EPP, a similar code:

```
<% $simplekey.each |$key, $value| { -%>
  <%= $key %>: <%= $value %>,
<% } -%>
```

results in (notice the missing quotation marks):

```
  hosts: [host1:8080, host2:8080],
```

Is there any way I can print the hosts array with quotation marks?

Puppet version: 6.23.0

Comment: I find your claim that the ERB version automatically introduces quotation marks surprising.  That's not what I would expect from the code presented alone.

Answer (score 0):

Super simple - just put the quotes in the EPP:

```
<% $simplekey.each |$key, $value| { -%>
  "<%= $key %>": <%= $value %>,
<% } -%>
```

Comment: This however does not work if you would like to use .join(',') on array and have the elements of array surrounded by quotes.

Comment: your answer actually would output something like:  `"hosts": [host1:8080, host2:8080],` not sure what exactly would happen if you put quotation marks on value field, but I guess something like: `"hosts": "[host1:8080, host2:8080]",` That again doesn't seem like wished result.